# I'm trying to search a string in a query result for certain numbers

Tags: php, mysql

My query result will be addresses. They will be similar to this:

123 JONES DR APT 1212

Some will not have an APT # because its a home or business.

For the ones that have an apartment number I want to bold the **APT 1212** part of the address. Some apartment numbers may be 3, 4 or even 5 digits. Some may contain a letter, such as APT C22.

Can anyone help me do that? I've researched here and come up with this but it only bolds the **APT**.

```
if (strrchr($row["Address"], "APT") == true)    {
    $keyword = "APT";
    $addr = preg_replace("/\w*?".preg_quote($keyword)."\w*/i", "<b>$0</b>", $row["Address"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not matching whitespace between the keyword and the number.

```
$addr = preg_replace('/\b' . preg_quote($keyword) . '\s*\w+/i', '<b>$0</b>', $row['Address']);
```

There's no need for `\w*?` before the keyword. But you should match a word boundary with `\b` so it won't match `APT` in the middle of a word.

Comment: Unbelievable. I've been reading and testing for most of the afternoon and you answer it in seconds, Thank you for your time, good sir.